# How can wget save only certains file types linked to from pages linked to by the target page?

Tags: linux, wget

How can wget save only certain file types linked to from pages linked to by the target page, regardless of the domain in which the certain files are?

Trying to speed up a task I have to do often.

I've been rooting through the wget docs and googling, but nothing seems to work. I keep on either getting just the target page or the subpages without the files (even using -H), so I'm obviously doing badly at this.

So, essentially, example.com/index1/ contains links to example.com/subpage1/ and example.com/subpage2/, while the subpages contain links to example2.com/file.ext and example2.com/file2.ext, etc. However, example.com/index1.html may link to example.com/index2/ which has links to more subpages I don't want.

Can wget even do this, and if not then what do you suggest I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Following command worked for me.

```
wget -r --accept "*.ext" --level 2 "example.com/index1/"
```

Need to do recursively so `-r` should be added.

Comment: This is not exactly the answer to the question. This makes wget download and then reject (delete) the file(s).

Comment: @JoelGMathew Great you mentioned that, but even better would telling us what the right command is.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should Work:

```
wget --accept "*.ext" --level 2 "example.com/index1/"
```

Comment: I've tried, but that only downloads example.com/index1/ for some reason... Which makes me a little suspicious since it isn't even that file type.

Comment: Can you provide the site or if not a sample(but real) site instead?

Comment: I Have same problem, I try use with: http://www.institutoveritas.net/livros-digitalizados.php